# ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

Hi every one i have some problem with Jboss-7-as.1.1 when i deploy i am getting `ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service` error.

```
10:44:30,343 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
10:44:30,765 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
10:44:31,750 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
10:44:32,031 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:44:34,062 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:44:34,984 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.1.GA
10:44:35,656 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
10:44:35,703 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
10:44:35,703 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
10:44:36,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "axis2.war"
10:44:36,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "responsecomponent.ear"
10:44:50,296 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,312 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,328 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry serializer.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,343 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/mail-1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,359 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry bcel.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-bind-1.1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,375 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jibx-run.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-bind-1.1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,375 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xpp3.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-bind-1.1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,390 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry stax-api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-bind-1.1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,406 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry wstx-asl.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jibx-bind-1.1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,421 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.0.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,421 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.0.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,437 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.0.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,453 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.0.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,468 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-impl-2.0.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,468 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-impl-2.0.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,484 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-impl-2.0.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,500 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/lib/jaxb-impl-2.0.2.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:50,515 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "responsecomponent.jar"
10:44:50,953 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."responsecomponent.ear".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."responsecomponent.ear".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "responsecomponent.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017224: Failed to parse service xml ["/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/META-INF/jboss-service.xml"]
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Unexpected element 'jboss-app'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:88)
    ... 6 more

10:44:58,953 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:58,968 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:58,968 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:58,984 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,000 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,015 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,031 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,031 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,046 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry bcel.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,062 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry jibx-run.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,078 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry xpp3.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,093 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry stax-api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,093 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry wstx-asl.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,109 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry xpp3.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-run-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,125 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry stax-api.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-run-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,140 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry wstx-asl.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jibx-run-1.2.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,156 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,171 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,171 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:44:59,187 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry serializer.jar in "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:45:00,796 WARN  [org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector] (MSC service thread 1-2) Unable to determine dialect of the StAX implementation at jar:file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/jboss-modules.jar!/
10:45:01,046 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ClusterBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-2) Clustering has been disabled
10:45:03,296 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deploying module: addressing-1.5 - file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempcb22ca251f6318fa/axis2.war-dcd99ebb654bec5f/WEB-INF/modules/addressing-1.5.mar
10:45:03,343 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deploying module: jaxws-1.5 - file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempcb22ca251f6318fa/axis2.war-dcd99ebb654bec5f/WEB-INF/modules/axis2-jaxws-mar-1.5.mar
10:45:04,218 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deploying module: script-1.5 - file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempcb22ca251f6318fa/axis2.war-dcd99ebb654bec5f/WEB-INF/modules/axis2-scripting-1.5.mar
10:45:04,281 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.5 - file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempcb22ca251f6318fa/axis2.war-dcd99ebb654bec5f/WEB-INF/modules/mex-1.5.mar
10:45:04,343 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.5 - file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempcb22ca251f6318fa/axis2.war-dcd99ebb654bec5f/WEB-INF/modules/mtompolicy-1.5.mar
10:45:04,406 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deploying module: ping-1.5 - file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempcb22ca251f6318fa/axis2.war-dcd99ebb654bec5f/WEB-INF/modules/ping-1.5.mar
10:45:05,375 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.5 - file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempcb22ca251f6318fa/axis2.war-dcd99ebb654bec5f/WEB-INF/modules/soapmonitor-1.5.mar
10:45:06,546 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deploying Web service: SPGenericConnectorVer2.aar - file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempcb22ca251f6318fa/axis2.war-dcd99ebb654bec5f/WEB-INF/services/SPGenericConnectorVer2.aar
10:45:06,656 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deploying Web service: version-1.5.aar - file:/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/tempcb22ca251f6318fa/axis2.war-dcd99ebb654bec5f/WEB-INF/services/version-1.5.aar
10:45:06,687 WARN  [org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet] (MSC service thread 1-2) No transportReceiver for org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener found. An instance for HTTP will be configured automatically. Please update your axis2.xml file!
10:45:06,765 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /axis2
10:45:06,796 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 55796ms - Started 181 of 256 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 72 services are passive or on-demand)
10:45:07,015 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "responsecomponent.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"responsecomponent.ear\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"responsecomponent.ear\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"responsecomponent.ear\""}}
10:45:07,031 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "axis2.war" was rolled back with no failure message
10:45:07,500 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment responsecomponent.jar in 482ms
10:45:11,468 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/] has not been started
10:45:11,703 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011942: Stopping OSGi Framework
10:45:11,734 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
10:45:11,734 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
```

Comment: `Message: Unexpected element 'jboss-app'` - could You post deployment descriptor?

Comment: Are you in process of migrating your application from an earlier version of jboss to jboss7.1?

Comment: Please post your Jboss-Service.xml.. we will be able to help you better then.

Answer (score 4):

The below is saying you put a jboss-app element inside the servers jboss-service.xml file.
No such element is allowed. You probably need to be more careful in your XML editor IDE interface when editing.

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017224: Failed to parse service xml ["/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/META-INF/jboss-service.xml"]
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Unexpected element 'jboss-app'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:88)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you migrating your application from an earlier version of jboss to jboss7?

follow [How to migrate an application from AS5,6 to AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7) post if you are migrating your app

**The following error**

```
    ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."responsecomponent.ear".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."responsecomponent.ear".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "responsecomponent.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_11]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017224: Failed to parse service xml ["/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/META-INF/jboss-service.xml"]
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Unexpected element 'jboss-app'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:88)
    ... 6 more
```

**See above..it is saying the following**

```
 Failed to parse service xml ["/D:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/bin/content/responsecomponent.ear/META-INF/jboss-service.xml
```

This is your error , and it also says

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
unexpected element 'jboss-app'
```

this is the cause of error

Remove that `jboss-app` tag.. it does not belong here

Check the structure of jboss-service.xml for Jboss AS7. With Jboss 7.1 we have different deployment descriptors

Refer to [Various deployment descriptors used](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+AS7.1) for list of deployment descriptors used with as7.1

**AS7 provides jboss-app.xml for overriding whats in application.xml please refer to above link for details.**

Regards